# Get anr traces using adb pull in kitkat

Tags: android

`adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt` is not working on kitkat.
It saying, `failed to copy '/data/anr/traces.txt' to './traces.txt': Permission denied`

What is wrong? Is this constrain introduced in Kitkat?

**Edit:**

This is not working on `Samsung-S4` after the upgrade to `Kitkat`. It is working fine on `Nexus-7`.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue on Samsung Galaxy S4. Even thou `adb pull` fails, I could access it with `adb shell` like so:

```
adb shell "cat /data/anr/traces.txt" | less
```

copying the trace works analog:

```
adb shell "cat /data/anr/traces.txt" > traces.txt
```